# Isolate minimal portion of text based on search terms from user input

Tags: php, search, text, text-extraction, ellipsis

How can I reduce a large paragraph of text down into information that is relevant to a search.

For example say I have a paragraph, and my search is `efficitur eget`

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec placerat libero id mi facilisis, at sagittis tortor porta. Donec eget sodales ipsum. Donec sagittis lacus mauris, et efficitur quam porttitor eu. Fusce eget consequat purus. Maecenas rutrum arcu viverra est rhoncus, et hendrerit tellus elementum. Aenean ornare dolor tempus ante porta, sit amet convallis lacus rutrum. Maecenas bibendum magna tortor. Vestibulum tortor nunc, dictum vitae nisl quis, pharetra mattis massa. Vestibulum vulputate leo eros, eget maximus ipsum tristique quis. Quisque rutrum vel felis eget feugiat. Etiam interdum nisi ac nibh egestas malesuada. Mauris fringilla nisi id rutrum fermentum. Ut ultrices ipsum rutrum, hendrerit urna non, dapibus ligula. Vivamus rhoncus eros eget eros feugiat volutpat. In ac arcu at purus porta varius. Sed commodo diam a ipsum vestibulum, et sagittis sem consectetur.
```

Is it possible to easily reduce the text down into single sentence that contains both `efficitur` and `eget`, without showing entire paragraph?

```
... Donec sagittis lacus mauris, et efficitur quam porttitor eu. Fusce eget consequat purus. Maecenas rutrum ...
```

Currently my puesdo idea is

```
// Find strpos of search words
// Make positions unique
// Find words closest together within X characters
// Allow for words on LEFT and RIGHT of keyword
// .. Continue until every keyword has lapsed
// Add "dots" to LEFT or/and RIGHT of the result
// implode
// return
```

But if this has already been done, or whether PHP has functionality to do this, I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, PHP has plenty of [string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) you can use to implement this. No, there is nothing built into PHP for native language processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written my own function, that will convert large paragraph to smaller sentences

```
function reduce_max_word_contents($content, $keywords, $exact, $max_words, $dots)
{
    
    if (is_array($keywords) == false) {
        $keywords = (array) $keywords;
        $keywords = array_filter($keywords);
    }
    
    $format_content = $content;
    $format_content = trim($format_content);
    
    if (empty($format_content)) {
        // trigger_error("No Content Given");
        return "";
    }
    
    if (empty($keywords)) {
        // trigger_error("No Keywords Given");
        return $format_content;
    }
    
    if (!$max_words) {
        // trigger_error("No Max Words Set");
        return $format_content;
    }
    
    $format_content_word_s = $format_content;
    $format_content_word_s = explode(' ', $format_content_word_s);
    $format_content_word_s = (array) $format_content_word_s;
    
    if (empty($format_content_word_s)) {
        // trigger_error("No Words Given");
        return $format_content;
    }
    
    $words_exceed_max = true;
    $words_exceed_max = ($words_exceed_max && !empty($format_content_word_s));
    $words_exceed_max = ($words_exceed_max && (count($format_content_word_s) > $max_words));
    $words_exceed_max = (bool) $words_exceed_max;
    
    if (!$words_exceed_max) {
        return $format_content;
    }
    
    $format_lower_words = $format_content_word_s;
    $format_lower_words = array_map('strtolower', $format_lower_words);
    $format_lower_words = array_map('trim', $format_lower_words);
    $format_lower_words = (array) $format_lower_words;
    
    if (empty($format_lower_words)) {
        return $format_content;
    }
    
    $keyword_indexes = array();
    
    foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword) {
        
        $keyword_lower = $keyword;
        $keyword_lower = trim($keyword_lower);
        $keyword_lower = strtolower($keyword_lower);
        
        $keyword_pos = false;
        
        if ($exact) {
            
            $keyword_pos = array_search($keyword_lower, $format_lower_words);
            
        } else {
            foreach ($format_lower_words as $f_key => $f_word) {
                
                $f_is_match = true;
                $f_is_match = ($f_is_match && strstr($f_word, $keyword_lower));
                $f_is_match = (bool) $f_is_match;
                
                if ($f_is_match) {
                    $keyword_pos = $f_key;
                    break;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        if (is_numeric($keyword_pos) == false) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $keyword_indexes[$key] = $keyword_pos;
        
    }
    
    if (empty($keyword_indexes)) {
        return $format_content;
    }
    
    $keyword_side_s = array();
    
    foreach (array_keys($keyword_indexes) as $k_key => $k_index) {
        
        $k_position = $keyword_indexes[$k_index];
        $k_position = intval($k_position);
        
        $left_slice           = array();
        $left_slice['offset'] = $k_position > $max_words ? $k_position - $max_words : 0;
        $left_slice['len']    = $k_position > $max_words ? $max_words : $k_position;
        
        if ($k_position > 0) {
            $array_left = array_slice($format_content_word_s, $left_slice['offset'], $left_slice['len'], true);
            $array_left = (array) $array_left;
        } else {
            $array_left = array();
        }
        
        $right_slice           = array();
        $right_slice['offset'] = $k_position + 1;
        $right_slice['len']    = $max_words - 1;
        
        $array_right = array_slice($format_content_word_s, $right_slice['offset'], $right_slice['len'], true);
        $array_right = (array) $array_right;
        
        $keyword_sides          = array();
        $keyword_sides['left']  = $array_left;
        $keyword_sides['right'] = $array_right;
        
        $s_result = array();
        
        $keywords_side_loop = array();
        $keywords_side_loop = array_keys($keyword_indexes);
        $keywords_side_loop = (array) $keywords_side_loop;
        
        foreach ($keywords_side_loop as $x_key) {
            
            $x_is_k = true;
            $x_is_k = ($x_is_k && ($k_index == $x_key));
            $x_is_k = (bool) $x_is_k;
            
            if ($x_is_k) {
                continue;
            }
            
            $x_key_pos = $keyword_indexes[$x_key];
            
            foreach ($keyword_sides as $kw_s_key => $kw_s_values) {
                
                if (array_key_exists($kw_s_key, $s_result)) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                $kw_s_is_valid = true;
                $kw_s_is_valid = ($kw_s_is_valid && !empty($kw_s_values));
                $kw_s_is_valid = ($kw_s_is_valid && !array_key_exists($x_key_pos, $kw_s_values));
                $kw_s_is_valid = (bool) $kw_s_is_valid;
                
                if ($kw_s_is_valid) {
                    $s_result[$kw_s_key] = $kw_s_values;
                } else {
                    $s_result[$kw_s_key] = array();
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        if (empty($s_result)) {
            $s_result = $keyword_sides;
        }
        
        $create_right_slice = true;
        $create_right_slice = ($create_right_slice && empty($s_result['right']));
        $create_right_slice = ($create_right_slice && isset($keyword_indexes[$k_index + 1]));
        $create_right_slice = (bool) $create_right_slice;
        // $create_right_slice = true; // good debug point
        
        if ($create_right_slice) {
            $right_word_slice = array_slice($format_content_word_s, $k_position + 1, $keyword_indexes[$k_index + 1] - 1, true);
            $right_word_slice = (array) $right_word_slice;
        } else {
            $right_word_slice = array();
        }
        
        if ($right_word_slice && !empty($right_word_slice)) {
            $s_result['connect'] = $right_word_slice;
        } else {
            $s_result['connect'] = array();
        }
        
        $keyword_side_s[$k_position] = $s_result;
        
    }
    
    if (empty($keyword_side_s)) {
        return $format_content;
    }
    
    $first_key = $keyword_side_s;
    reset($first_key);
    $first_key = key($first_key);
    
    $keyword_side_s_keys          = array();
    $keyword_side_s_keys['start'] = $first_key;
    $keyword_side_s_keys['end']   = array_pop(array_keys($keyword_side_s));
    
    $keyword_result_s = array();
    
    foreach (array_keys($keyword_side_s) as $ks_key => $ks_position) {
        
        $ks_sides = $keyword_side_s[$ks_position];
        $ks_sides = (array) $ks_sides;
        
        $section_left_dots = !empty($keyword_result_s) ? $dots : "";
        $section_left_dots = (string) $section_left_dots;
        
        $section_right_dots = array_keys($keyword_side_s);
        $section_right_dots = isset($section_right_dots[$ks_key + 1]);
        $section_right_dots = $section_right_dots ? $dots : "";
        $section_right_dots = (string) $section_right_dots;
        
        $ks_word = $format_content_word_s[$ks_position];
        $ks_word = (string) $ks_word;
        
        $keyword_section = array();
        
        if (!empty($ks_sides['left'])) {
            $keyword_section[] = $section_left_dots;
            $keyword_section[] = implode(' ', $ks_sides['left']);
        }
        
        $keyword_section[] = $ks_word;
        
        if (!empty($ks_sides['connect'])) {
            $keyword_section[] = implode(' ', $ks_sides['connect']);
        }
        
        if (!empty($ks_sides['right'])) {
            $keyword_section[] = implode(' ', $ks_sides['right']);
            $keyword_section[] = $section_right_dots;
        }
        
        $keyword_section_s = $keyword_section;
        $keyword_section_s = array_map('trim', $keyword_section_s);
        $keyword_section_s = array_filter($keyword_section_s);
        $keyword_section_s = (array) $keyword_section_s;
        
        if (empty($keyword_section_s)) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $keyword_result_s = array_merge($keyword_result_s, $keyword_section_s);
        $keyword_result_s = (array) $keyword_result_s;
        
    }
    
    $keyword_result_str = $keyword_result_s;
    $keyword_result_str = array_map('trim', $keyword_result_str);
    $keyword_result_str = array_filter($keyword_result_str);
    $keyword_result_str = array_unique($keyword_result_str);
    $keyword_result_str = implode(' ', $keyword_result_str);
    
    if (empty($keyword_result_str)) {
        return $format_content;
    }
    
    if (!empty($keyword_side_s[$keyword_side_s_keys['start']]['left'])) {
        $keyword_result_str = $dots . $keyword_result_str;
    }
    
    if (!empty($keyword_side_s[$keyword_side_s_keys['end']]['right'])) {
        $keyword_result_str = $keyword_result_str . $dots;
    }
    
    return $keyword_result_str;
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that will process one or more needles, search the haystack string using case-insensitivity and word boundaries, find the shortest string which includes the most unique matches, then isolates the whole leading and trailing sentences that the first and last word are found in.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/D7NK2))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec placerat libero id mi facilisis, at sagittis tortor porta. Donec eget sodales ipsum. Donec sagittis lacus mauris, et efficitur quam porttitor eu. Fusce eget consequat purus. Maecenas rutrum arcu viverra est rhoncus, et hendrerit tellus elementum. Aenean ornare dolor tempus ante porta, sit amet convallis lacus rutrum. Maecenas bibendum magna tortor. Vestibulum tortor nunc, dictum vitae nisl quis, pharetra mattis massa. Vestibulum vulputate leo eros, eget maximus ipsum tristique quis. Quisque rutrum vel felis eget feugiat. Etiam interdum nisi ac nibh egestas malesuada. Mauris fringilla nisi id rutrum fermentum. Ut ultrices ipsum rutrum, hendrerit urna non, dapibus ligula. Vivamus rhoncus eros eget eros feugiat volutpat. In ac arcu at purus porta varius. Sed commodo diam a ipsum vestibulum, et sagittis sem consectetur.
TEXT;

$needles = [
    'efficitur',
    'eget',
    'Ipsum',
];

// sort longer strings first
array_multisort(
    array_map('strlen', $needles),
    SORT_DESC,
    $needles
);

// build pattern with word boundaries and an atomic group to ensure longer strings are prioritized over shorter strings
$pattern = '#\b(?>' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $needles)) . ')\b#i';

// get all matches and their offsets
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    $narrowestWordOffsets = [];
    $fullSetCount = null;
    $totalLength = null;
    // get unique combinations
    foreach ($m[0] as $i => [$w, $o]) {
        $set = [$w => $o];
        foreach (array_slice($m[0], $i + 1) as [$w2, $o2]) {
            if (!isset($set[$w2])) {
                $set[$w2] = $o2;
                $lastWord = $w2;
            }
        }
        $setLength = strlen($lastWord) + $set[$lastWord] - current($set);
        // store the best qualifying combinations of found words
        if (
            !$narrowestWordOffsets
            || (
                $setLength < $totalLength
                && count($set) === $fullSetCount
            ) 
        ) {
            $narrowestWordOffsets = $set;
            $totalLength = $setLength;
            $fullSetCount ??= count($set);
        }
    }
    // Isolate the desired output string and add optional ellipses
    var_export(
        preg_replace_callback(
            '#(.*?)([^.]*' . preg_quote(substr($text, current($narrowestWordOffsets), $totalLength)) . '[^.]*\.?)(.*)#',
            fn($m) =>
                (strlen($m[1]) ? '...' : '')
                . $m[2]
                . (strlen($m[3]) ? ' ...' : ''),
            $text
        )
    );
} else {
    echo 'No needles found in haystack';
}
```